# "There was an error running python" in Rodeo IDE

Tags: python, path, rodeo

After a fresh install of anaconda and a fresh install of Rodeo, I'm still getting:

> `There was an error running python` when I try to set my path.

When I type `which python` into terminal, I get: `/Library/anaconda/bin/python`

Looking at my `~/.bash_profile`, I have the following:

```
export PATH="/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Library/anaconda/bin:$PATH"
export PATH="/Library/cling_jupyter/bin:$PATH"
```

When I try to set my `which python` path in Rodeo:

[image]

I get:

[image]

The weird thing is... the last output from the error:

[image]

Is an old path from an old anaconda installation.

And the other weird thing:

[image]

I have two 'pythons' in my bin folder. One is a .app and the other is an alias that actually points to the python3.5 file.

I have tried the following:

- http://rodeo.yhat.com/docs/#changing-your-python-path
- [Discover which version of Python is in PATH and how to change it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34459302/discover-which-version-of-python-is-in-path-and-how-to-change-it)
- [How to install Rodeo IDE in Anaconda python distribution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31935714/how-to-install-rodeo-ide-in-anaconda-python-distribution)

But nothing has worked. Please help! I'd really love to get Rodeo on my system.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you have multiple anaconda's on your machine and the `/Library` one isn't configured correctly, so Rodeo is reverting to an old one.

Easiest thing to fix this is to remove anaconda completely and reinstall.  I'd check out [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22585235/python-anaconda-how-to-safely-uninstall) on uninstalling.

The "normal" spot for anaconda to install is your home directory: `~/`

Other things to check:

- Running `which -a python` will list all the pythons on your system.
- Running `which -a conda` will list all the condas on your system.
- Check your `.bashrc` and `.bash_profiles` to make sure there aren't any rogue python paths being exported

(also be sure you have jupyter installed as well: `pip install jupyter`)

Comment: Running `which -a conda` just lists one anaconda, however, `which -a python` shows two pythons: (1) /Library/anaconda/bin/python
(2) /usr/bin/python. (2) seems to be the offending python? `.bashrc` doesn't exist on my machine. But the paths in `.bash_profiles` seem to be okay. Any thoughts?

Comment: I ended up nuking my computer and starting from a fresh install. Rodeo is now up and running... never could figure out the root cause (I have a feeling it had something to do with a Cling Kernel for Jupyter installation gone wrong)